# ImportError: No module named parse in installing pymongo, python 2.7

Tags: python, pymongo

I am installing pymongo in windows in python 2.7.

but I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named parse

What should I do?

I do not have python 3 installed on my machine.

I installed pymongo before and it was working but suddenly when again I run my program it gave me this error.

Comment: Can you show the code and the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had my script named urllib.py and it intefered with default files. I renamed it and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your are running Python 3 modules with Python 2.7.

Python 2.7 imports parse like this:

`from urlparse import urlparse`

While Python 3 uses:

`from urllib.parse import urlparse`

So this results in an `ImportError`, because the `parse` your Python 3 Pymongo is trying to import, does not exist in the Python 2.7 you are using.